# How to use Azure Notification Hubs?

Tags: c#, windows, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I have an app that consists of an article section which I would like to update from time to time through Azure. Does Azure Notification Hubs provide this feature? Or it just notifies the  users that update is available?

For example news app where articles goes on changing and newer articles are highlighted too.

I am developing it as windows phone application. What I need know to implement it? Any tutorial would you like me to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Notification Hub is the service that implements for you boilerplate code, platform capabilities and scalability. In a nutshell, it will deliver the notification, nothing more.

If you need to update your application, you need to implement it in the app - to get the notification, extract the content from it and update what you need. We needed to do the same - update the content in the application from the server whenever the new content is available, and in the end of the day implemented the update with every application launch and when the notification comes.

As for development questions, please take a look at that [series of tutorials](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/). These tutorials cover your platform and all of the steps you need to do to implement the notification hubs + your app project.
For receiving notifications in WP, take a look at that [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202977(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: Do you have any procedure of doing what you suggested? Is there any link or video that I can follow?

Comment: @user5158017 what is the platform and language you are using for the development?

Comment: C# is the language & windows phone app is the platform.Is it different for universal app & the windows phone app?

Comment: @user5158017 added some info to the answer.